# Which CMS would be better to use?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I want to create website where I want to put lessons about python. I'm thinking of DLE or Wordpess. What would you recommend me of these, or you can advise of something else?

Comment: WordPress is the ideal platform IMHO very easy to use and customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty huge question, and really depends upon what you are aiming to achieve with the final site.

For me, I use Wordpress for just about all the sites I build. It's incredibly flexible, especially thanks to the huge range of plugins that extend functionality to whatever you require.

Comment: I want to post one lesson per 2 days

Comment: Wordpress works well regarding how easy it is to update with new content. You could potentially use custom post types to create 'lessons', from which you could add all the information required.

Comment: It will be in Russian and also it's aimed to either newbies and professionals